# kivy.factory.FactoryException: Unknown class <WindowManager>

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I don't know why, but every time I try to run my code it doesn't work, here's the code.
If you can help me it'd be really wholesome. Thank you in advance.

Here's the code of the 3 files.

main.py

```
from kivy.app import App

from App.Constructor.constructor import Constructor


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Constructor().constr()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

constructor.py

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager

kv = Builder.load_file('Constructor\\constructor.kv')

class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

class Constructor():
    def constr(self):
        return kv
```

constructor.kv

```
#:import Login App.Login
#:import SignUp App.SignUp

WindowManager:
    Login:
    SignUp:


<Login>:
    name: "login"

<SignUp>:
    name: "signup"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This because of you used the `WindowManager` in kv file before you define it in the python file
The solution will be to load the kv file after creating the `WindowManager` class
like this
1)

```py
class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass
kv = Builder.load_file('Constructor\\constructor.kv')
```

or
2)
loading directly when you need it

```py
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager


class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

class Constructor():
    def constr(self):
        return Builder.load_file('Constructor\\constructor.kv')
```